# Django Models -- filtering on whether a tuple of fields is in a list of tuples

Tags: sql, regex, django, django-models

**Edit: see code below for less reading**

I have tried to simplify the example, but it is still a little convoluted. I suspect I may have to rewrite my models to better support this search.
Say I have a Course model with associated days and start/end times. I also have a list of currently added Courses. I wish to return all Courses which don't conflict with my currently added Courses.

The days are stored as a character field: "MoTuWeThFr" would represent a class taking place on every day of the week. The start and end time are each just a django date-time field.

I am able to get a list of tuples of days and associated times that would conflict. For example, I could get the list [('Mo', 08:00, 10:00), ('We', 08:00, 10:00), ('Th', 12:00, 13:00)]. I need to return all Courses such that if its "days" field contains 'Mo', its start/end times don't overlap with (08:00, 10:00), and if it contains 'Th', its start/end times don't overlap with (12:00, 13:00), etc...

I think could achieve filtering on just days or just times by using regular expressions. For example, if the "invalid" days are ['Mo', 'We', 'Th'], just write a regex expression that matches any string containing any of those days, and then exclude any course with 'days' that match the regex. But I am unsure how to "link" the time and day while filtering. Perhaps if I made a new field in my model for both day and time, like day_time="MoWeFr 08:00-10:00". It might then be possible to programmatically create a regex with one clause for every tuple in my exclusion list. But would this be efficient? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I know this question might be too specific to be broadly useful, but it seems like such a reasonable use-case, I am surprised the resulting database lookup is so tricky.

I have included a more specific example with pseudocode below:
in models.py:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
    days = models.CharField()
```

Example Course:

```
start_time = 08:00
end_time = 10:00
days = 'MoWeFr'
```

in views.py:

```
current_courses = [('Mo', 08:00, 10:00), ('We', 08:00, 10:00), ('Th', 12:00, 13:00)]

# returns all courses that don't conflict with times in current_courses
non_conflict_courses = Course.objects.exclude(...)
```

Example filtering on only days (for ['Mo', 'We', 'Th']):

```
Course.objects.exclude(days__iregex=r'(\w\w)*(Mo)(\w\w)*|(\w\w)*(We)(\w\w)*|(\w\w)*(Th)(\w\w)*')
```

How can I filter/exclude on both days and times simultaneously? I am unsure how to "link" them.

Comment: already wrote this one..... its a tough one. Any chance you could put this in code. A lot of writing.

Comment: I would put the days in their own boolean columns. Well if you want some speed.

Comment: The field `days` contains denormalized values. I personally don't like that design at all. Can you switch to PostgreSQL as backend database? If yes, then I'd suggest you to use `ArrayField` for `days`. Your example would be then stored as `['Mo', 'We', 'Fr']`. But what if a course has different start and/or end time on different days? If you have that requirement you could even go for a `JSONField`. Ditch the regex. It makes your code hard to maintain, the performance can be an issue too.

Comment: Thank you @cezar and Bensiali for the suggestions. I agree about the regex being hard to maintain, so I will switch to having a boolean field for each day. Unfortunately I cannot easily switch to PostgreSQL, but that may be a possibility later on. Luckily a course will always have the same time each day, so the ArrayField should be sufficient if/when I do switch. Thank you again for the advice.